# What changes I need to do on the restored DB and how?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hp-quality-center

I have restored a DB from "mixed authentication" MS SQL Server into "windows authentication only" SQL Server.

My application is configured for windows authentication which uses 'dbo' for accessing DB.

But in the restored DB , all the tables, views are NOT owned by 'dbo'

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure if i understood the question, but i guess when you accessing database, you are/was creating the tables. Most possibly your statements was like:

```
Create Table TableName (...)
```

To create tables in specific schema, you should add schema prefix (or [change the default schema of user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) you are using):

```
Create Table dbo.TableName (...)
```

To move tables to other schema, see [Alter Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Janis. My requirement is I need to change the schema for all tables and views as well,because they are not owned by 'dbo'.